# How to download files from a direct link with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey there I am new to nodejs and i am making a app manager with it.

In the app manager I want to download files from the direct links like:

`https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.zip`

if I click that link I will download the files but I want to do this in NodeJS.

can anyone tell me how will I do this?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by node.js? 
Do you want to upload files to the server running on node.js or something else?

Comment: @MatasLesinskas It looks like OP wants to enter a URL, have NodeJS (ran locally) retrieve that file from the given URL, and save the file to OP's local hard drive / ssd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = “...” // whatever url you want
const filePath = “...” // where ever you want save the file along with the file name you want and extension example (here/file.zip)

const file = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
const request = http.get(url, (response) => {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Try this code